# How do I get the background url from css Selenium Webdriver

Tags: css, selenium, junit, webdriver

I'm trying to check the url of an image, located in a div - in the 'background:' - in the CSS for the page.  But when 'get' the CssValue and display it just shows blank.

The html for the div is:

```
<div class="Welcome">

<h3>Welcome</h3>
.......
</div>
```

...and the CSS for the div is:

```
div.Welcome {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("imageurl") no-repeat scroll center 25px;
float: left;
margin: 50px 20px 50px 150px;
padding-top: 230px;
width: 300px;
}
```

I've tried to locate as below:

```
WebElement WelcomeImg = driver.findElement(By className("Welcome"));

String WelImg = WelcomeImg.getCssValue("background");

Assert.assertTrue(WelImg.contains("imageurl"));
```

I've also tried with

```
("background-url");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The URL is defined in `background-image`.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should try with new thing! Get the background image property and let me know whether it worked.

```
WebElement WelcomeImg = driver.findElement(By className("Welcome"));
String WelImg = WelcomeImg.getCssValue("background-image");
Assert.assertTrue(WelImg.contains("imageurl"));
```

Hope, it may help you.